Transferring Animated Empties to Armature (Motion Capture)
I have recently started a project trying to implement a one camera Motion Capture system. I used a 3D pose estimation Machine Learning model to predict 3D-coordinates on a human body from a video input. I managed to turn those coordinates into animated empties (see attached GIF). Now my goal would be to somehow transfer this motion onto an armature (ideally, onto a Mixamo rig). I'm not sure if this is even possible and I'm a total noob when it comes to rigging and armatures but hopefully someone can help.


CGDive did a series of videos on motion capture and retargeting in Blender here which might help.  Not sure whether it dealt with retargeting Empties though as I've not watched it.

Select the Mixamo armature, go to pose mode, select all bones, press S to scale them matching the empties proportions as much as you can.
In Object mode Apply the Armature modifier to the model, back on Armature pose mode Apply the scale (Ctrl A), go to Edit mode and check that bones aren't connected each other (Alt P > Disconnect Bone, if available).
Add to the model a new Armature modifier, targeting the rig.
Now in Armature pose mode apply to every bone two Bone constraints: one Copy location and one Damped Track, targeting the relevant Empty.
When finished go to Pose Menu > Animation > Bake action (Visual Keying, Delete constraints, Overwrite current).
Don't confuse Object constraints with Bone constraints (it's a frequent error).


Thank you! I solved it in a simlar way by creating an armature which connects the empties and then adding bone constraints as you described. After baking the animation, I retargeted it to a Mixamo rig.
